# UILocalNotification sound plays every other time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, uilocalnotification

Whenever I create a UILocalNotification and it gets fired, the custom sound I have only plays every second instance. This only occurs outside the simulator, on my iPhone 5s.

```
UILocalNotification* sessionEndNotification = [UILocalNotification new];
sessionEndNotification.fireDate = [self.dateAppMinimized dateByAddingTimeInterval:[self secondsLeft]];
sessionEndNotification.alertBody = @"Your session has finished. Remember to remain mindful through the rest of your day!";
sessionEndNotification.soundName = @"bell.caf";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:sessionEndNotification];
```

If I change the soundName to UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName it works every time. bell.caf is 8 seconds long.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify more details? It's not so clear.

Comment: Basically every 2nd time the notification is deployed (while the phone is locked) the sound doesn't play and it doesn't vibrate. So it works half the time. If I use the default sound name, it works every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, but not by doing anything that makes sense. I changed the code to this and it works:

```
UILocalNotification* sessionEndNotification = [UILocalNotification new];
sessionEndNotification.soundName = @"endMeditationBell.aif";
sessionEndNotification.hasAction = YES;
sessionEndNotification.fireDate = [self.dateAppMinimized dateByAddingTimeInterval:[self secondsLeft]];
sessionEndNotification.alertTitle = @"Session finished";
sessionEndNotification.alertBody = @"Your session has finished. Remember to remain mindful through the rest of your day!";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:sessionEndNotification];
```

Comment: Didn't work for me and I'm having the same "every other time the custom sound goes off" problem. I'll keep trying different stuff!